# Linux telnet client with multiline support

Tags: telnet

I need to post data like this to an open telnet

```
{
  "context" : "50EF2767",
  "data" : {
    "user_status" : "invisible"
  },
  "command" : "setStatus"
}
```

The data is multiline. I cannot copy-paste it, as telnet treats new lines as Enter.

I tried http://telnet-online.net/ and it works fine 
[image: Strips new lines]

But I need this for localhost.

Is there any telnet client or any way to allow to post multiline data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try netcat (`nc`). See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/?utm_source=feedburner for examples on how to use it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion.

I tried
`nc localhost 8080 `

Thought it allows to post multiline, it strips brackets

So I post

```
{
  "context" : "50EF2767",
  "data" : {
    "user_status" : "invisible"
  },
  "command" : "setStatus"
}
```

but the server recievs 

```
  "context" : "50EF2767",
  "data" : {
    "user_status" : "invisible"
  },
  "command" : "setStatus"
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Well, it basically works if prepending and postpending my data with new lines. There is a minor problem that if prepending a newline, it posts 2 messages - empty line and then the data. But without prepending it doesn't post the first bracket {